# List the "ID" once if all rows with that ID meet the criteria

Tags: php, sql

I have a table containing orders, and another table containing every line item on all orders:

```
SALES                ITEMSALELINES
Order |              Order | Line | QtyOrdered | InStock
1     |              1     | 1    | 1          | 5
2     |              1     | 2    | 1          | 2
                     2     | 1    | 1          | 5
                     2     | 2    | 3          | 2
```

I need to display a list of all my orders that have enough stock on on every line item. For example, order 1 would be listed, since we have enough inventory in stock, but order 2 would not, because the second line has ordered more than we have in stock.

I am thinking I need to to use the "NOT EXISTS" statement in some way.

What would the SQL statement be?

Answer (score 0):

Only select the orders where Instock > QtyOrdered. Something like this should work.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
WHERE InStock > QtyOrdered
```

edit: missed the two table part, I'll be back :)

Answer (score 0):

By using `NOT IN` :

```
SELECT *
FROM   `SALES`
WHERE  `Order` 
NOT IN(
    SELECT `Order`
    FROM   `ITEMSALELINES`
    WHERE  `QtyOrdered` > `InStock`
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't recall if all flavors support NOT IN, I know SQL Server and Oracle do.

```
SELECT Order
FROM  Sales
WHERE Order NOT IN (SELECT Order
                    FROM ITEMSALELINES
                    WHERE QtyOrdered > InStock)
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c2b37/12)**

```
SELECT s.`Order`
FROM `SALES` s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0
                  FROM `ITEMSALELINES` sl
                  WHERE sl.`QtyOrdered` > sl.`InStock`
                  AND sl.`Order` = s.`Order`)
```

Result:

```
| ORDER |
---------
|     1 |
```